# Tracking work towards awards in MS Excel

Tags: excel, report, lookup

I’m trying to create a report from existing data about tasks people have completed and whether they can give given awards for completion of the tasks

I have a list of people who have been working to complete tasks in an exhaustive list, completion of which is recorded in an Excel sheet with ticks or similar characters. (table 1.)

[image: task per person]

For each of these people, awards can be given when various subsets of these tasks are completed. The tasks required for these awards overlap and are maintained in a list per award. (table 2.)

[image: tasks per award]

I would like to generate a report which identifies for each person how many tasks he or she has completed toward each award. I will use this report to identify if they can be given the award or how many more tasks they need to complete.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it... If you change the tick marks to a numeric value of one (1), you can add formulas to additional columns on the table (or a separate sheet).

```
     |   A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H        I        J        K         L          M          N      
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
  1  |          task01   task02   task03   task04   task05   task06   task07   task08   task09   task10   Award 01   Award 02   Award 03  
  2  | name01   1        1        1        1        1                 1                                   Yes        No         No        
  3  | name02   1                                            1        1                                   No         No         No        
  4  | name03   1        1                                   1        1        1        1        1        No         Yes        No        
  5  | name04   1                                                     1                                   No         No         No        
  6  | name05   1                 1        1                          1                                   No         No         No        
  7  | name06   1        1                                            1                                   No         No         No        
  8  | name07   1        1                          1        1        1        1        1        1        No         Yes        Yes       
  9  | name08                                                         1                 1                 No         No         No        
  10 | name09                                                         1                                   No         No         No        
  11 | name10                                                         1                                   No         No         No
```

The formulas used in L2, M2, and N2:

```
=IF(SUM(B2:F2)=5,"Yes","No")
=IF(SUM(G2:K2)=5,"Yes","No")
=IF(SUM(C2,F2,I2,J2,K2)=5,"Yes","No")
```